# Chained multiple pipeline based on 'post' jenkins block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm beginner to Jenkins. I have code pipeline structure like this
             `Repo1 -> Repo2 -> Repo3 -> Deploy`
I already created such hierarchy via GUI but I want to create it via pipeline as code.I want to create chain of pipelines where I clone different repos and perform tests on it and then continue to another repo based on current pipeline post result.

This is my jenkinsfile - (psuedo code like as it gives me error to build)

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build Repo1') {
        steps {
            sh 'echo "repo1 build!"'
        }
    }
    stage('Test Repo1') {
        steps {
            sh 'echo "repo success!"'
        }
    }        
}
post {
    success {
            pipeline {
                agent any
                stages {
                    stage('Build Repo2') {
                        steps {
                            sh 'echo "build repo2!"'
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Test Repo2') {
                        steps {
                            sh 'echo "test repo2!"'
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                post {
                    success {
                        # continue to generate pipeline for repo3
                        echo 'This will always run'
                    }
                    failure {
                        echo 'This will run only if failed'
                    }                        
                }
            }
    }
    failure {
        echo 'This will run only if failed'
    }
    unstable {
        echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'
    }
    changed {
        echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'
        echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'
    }
}
```

}

Please help!

Comment: AFAIK nested pipeline blocks in declarative pipeline doesn't support. Instead of nested pipeline blocks make use of Stages and Steps.